# Is there a way to force a newline in Puppet log messages?

Tags: logging, puppet

When I output an error message in puppet, such as with Puppet.err (from a Ruby module), it is displayed in the Puppet Enterprise console log in a difficult to read fashion, because in HTML, newlines are ignored. If I try to insert line breaks (HTML **<br/>** tags) before each newline, Puppet escapes them by turning the angle brackets into HTML entities.

Is there a way to tell Puppet to include newlines or not escape the br tags? Perhaps a place in the puppet source code that I can change to get this behavior? For example, I call Puppet.err. Where is this function defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logging methods are created in a bit of a [mystical fashion](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/1c274b36a61bea0d4fba80a0dfe81de41c1457db/lib/puppet/util/logging.rb#L12-20).

For what it's worth, I disbelieve that core Puppet is escaping the HTML, it's more likely a commodity feature of the Console itself.

You could try and hook your reports up to Puppet Explorer or puppet-board, see if you fare better with either of those. But I'm not sure how well this will play with PE.

Comment: I eventually tracked the place the logging methods were being created. Mystical is right! I had to use the source_location method off the method object to find it.